# Keep selected rows persistent in lightning datatable between two tabs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable, aura-attribute, lightning-tab

I have 2 lightning tabs, each of them have a lightning data table in it.

1.The first tab displays a search filter and displays options accordingly
2.Each tab has a checkbox and you can select the options.
3.The 2nd tab displays all the selected options from the first tab.
4.There is a remove button against each row in 2nd tab

**Requirement is:-**
when I select an option from first tab data table--> display automatically in 2nd tab.
when I remove an option from 2nd tab datatable--> uncheck it simultaneously from first tab
datatable also.

**My issue is:-**
When I remove an option it is not reflecting in the first tab datatable. However when I reselect category(onChange of category) I am able to see the updated options. How do I achieve this without having to reselect the category each time?

My code

```
<aura:component controller="SitePlanController" 
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}" />
    
    <lightning:card>
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="9">
                
                <lightning:layoutItem size="4" class="slds-m-left_large">
                    <lightning:tabset selectedTabId="{! v.selectedTabId}">
                        <lightning:tab label="Add options" id="AO_view" onactive="{! c.handleActiveAO }">
                        </lightning:tab>
                        <lightning:tab label="Selected options" id="SO_view" onactive="{! c.handleActiveSO }" >
                        </lightning:tab>
                    </lightning:tabset>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedTabId == 'AO_view'}">          
                    
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="2">
                        <lightning:select label="Category" aura:id="category_selector" class="slds-m- 
                                                                                              bottom_medium" onchange="{! c.onCategorySelect }" >
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            <aura:iteration items="{! v.categories}" var="c">
                                <option value="{!c.Id}" selected="{!c.Id == v.categoryId}" >{!c.Display_Name__c}</option>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </lightning:select>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="1"></lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="3" class="slds-m-top_x-large">
                        <p>{! v.instruction}</p>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="8">
                        <div class="slds-panel__body">
                            <lightning:datatable columns="{! v.tableFields }" data="{! v.options }" keyField="id"
                                                 onrowaction="{! c.showOptionDetail}" onrowselection="{! c.selectOption}"
                                                 selectedRows="{! v.selectedRows}" />
                        </div>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{! v.option}">
                            <div
                                 class="slds-panel slds-panel_docked slds-panel_docked-right slds-is-open slds-text- 
                                        align_center slds-m-right_medium slds-m-top_large"
                                 aria-hidden="false">
                                <p class="slds-text-body_regular">{! v.option.description}</p>
                                <img class="product_image slds-m-top_small" src="{!v.imgPrefixURL + v.option.imageId}" />
                            </div>
                        </aura:if>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedTabId == 'SO_view'}">
                            
                            <lightning:layoutItem size="8">
                                <div class="slds-panel__body">
                                    <lightning:datatable aura:id="AOTable" columns="{! v.tableFieldsSO }" data="{! v.allUserSelectedOptions }" keyField="id"
                                                         hideCheckboxColumn ="true" onrowaction="{! c.removeRow}" />
                                </div>
                            </lightning:layoutItem>
                            
                        </aura:if>
                        
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js**

```
({
    onInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.showCategories(cmp);
    },
    showOptionDetail: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var option = event.getParam("row"); 
        cmp.set("v.option", option);   
    },
    onCategorySelect: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var categoryId = cmp.find("category_selector").get("v.value");
        cmp.set("v.categoryId", categoryId);
        cmp.set("v.selectedcategoryId",categoryId);
        
        if(categoryId){
            var categories = cmp.get("v.categories");
            var i=0;
            while(categories[i].Id != categoryId){i++;}
            cmp.set("v.instruction", categories[i].Instruction__c);
            helper.showOptions(cmp, categoryId);
        }else{
            cmp.set("v.options", []);
            cmp.set("v.instruction", "");
        }
    },
    selectOption: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var categoryId = cmp.get("v.categoryId");
        var allSelectedOptions = cmp.get("v.allSelectedOptions");
        if(allSelectedOptions.length == 0){allSelectedOptions = [];}
        
        // Get selected option Ids 
        var selectedRows = event.getParam("selectedRows");
        console.log('c.selectop selectedRows'+selectedRows);
        if(selectedRows.length == 0) {
            selectedRows = [];
        } else {
            var temp = [];
            selectedRows.forEach(function(option){
                temp.push(option.id);
            });
            selectedRows = temp;
        }
        
        //To get id of selected options
        cmp.set("v.selectedRowsId",selectedRows);
        //var c = cmp.get(v.selectedRowsId);
        //console.log('selectedRowsId'+c);
        
        // Replace options for current category with updated ones
        var i=0;
        while(i<allSelectedOptions.length && allSelectedOptions[i].categoryId != categoryId){i++;}
        if(i<allSelectedOptions.length){
            allSelectedOptions[i].categoryId = categoryId;
            allSelectedOptions[i].options = selectedRows;
        } else {
            allSelectedOptions.push({categoryId: categoryId, options: selectedRows});
        }
        cmp.set("v.allSelectedOptions", allSelectedOptions);
        var x = cmp.get('v.allSelectedOptions');
        console.log('allSelectedOptions'+x);;        
    },
    
    //loads content when the Selected options tab is selected
    handleActiveSO: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var s = cmp.get("v.selectedRowsId");
        cmp.set("v.selectedTabId", 'SO_view');
        helper.ShowAllUserSelectedoptions(cmp,s);
    },
    
    //loads content when the Add option tab is selected
    handleActiveAO: function (cmp, event, helper) { },
    
    //handle remove row action in 'selected options' tab
    removeRow: function (cmp, event, helper){
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        var actname = action.name;
        var row = event.getParam('row');
        var categoryId = cmp.get("v.categoryId");
        
        if (actname === 'delete') {
            helper.removeOption(cmp, row);
        } 
    }
})
```

**Helper.js**

```
       ({
            showCategories: function (cmp) {
                cmp.set("v.categories", categories);
            }else {
                $A.log("callback error", res.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    showOptions: function (cmp, categoryId) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getOptions");
        action.setParams({"categoryId": categoryId});
        action.setCallback(this, function (res) {
            var state = res.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var options = res.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set("v.options", options);
                this.showSelectedOptions(cmp, categoryId);
            }
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    showSelectedOptions: function (cmp, categoryId) {
        var allSelectedOptions = cmp.get("v.allSelectedOptions");
        
        var i=0;
        while(i<allSelectedOptions.length && allSelectedOptions[i].categoryId != categoryId){i++;}
        if(allSelectedOptions[i] && allSelectedOptions[i].options){
            cmp.set("v.selectedRows", allSelectedOptions[i].options);
        }
        var x = cmp.get("v.selectedRows");
    },

    ShowAllUserSelectedoptions: function(cmp,userselectedoptionIds){

        var action = cmp.get("c.getallUserSelectedOptions");
        action.setParams({"userselectedoptionIds": userselectedoptionIds});
        action.setCallback(this, function (res) {
            var state = res.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var useroptions = res.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set("v.allUserSelectedOptions", useroptions);
                
            }e

    removeOption: function (cmp, row) {

        var removedrowid = row.id;
              
        var rows = cmp.get('v.allUserSelectedOptions');
        var AOrows = cmp.get('v.allSelectedOptions');
       var SOrowId = cmp.get('v.selectedRows');
       
         //remove row from 'selected options' tab
        var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row);
        rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
        cmp.set('v.allUserSelectedOptions', rows);         
            //remove row from 'Add options' tab
            for(var i = 0; i < SOrowId.length; i++){
                if(SOrowId[i] == removedrowid){
                    SOrowId.splice(i, 1);
                    cmp.set("v.selectedRows", SOrowId);
                    cmp.set("v.selectedRowsId",SOrowId );
                    cmp.set("v.allSelectedOptions",SOrowId);
                }              
            }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1.- pass the row data to a parent component, which in returns passes down the data to the children components (aka, your different tabs).

2.- use something to manage your application state, such as the browser's [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

this way, your selected rows will persist across your different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the issue you explained, i can think of introducing Lightning events into your architecture. If i understand your UI correctly, does it look like below?

[image]

---

If the above understanding is right, then you might want to look at event communication in Aura available in this page.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_intro.htm

Let me know if helps!

Comment: Yes my UI looks exactly like this. Does this mean I have to put my components in a hierarchy. ?Currently there is no parent child hierarchy in my complement to use events.

Comment: That's great. Not required to be in hierarchy. You can use the example in below git to get an idea.

https://github.com/sunilkumarmadana/lightning-tab-set